# How to display other data when you select the supplier name in select tag in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'd like to select a name and output it properties in form automatically, how do I display its properties automatically?

```
        <select id="suppliers_name" name="suppliers_name" class="form-control" data-plugin="select2">
            @foreach ($supplier as $suppliers)
            <option value="{{$suppliers->name}}">{{$suppliers->supplier_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Supplier/s Address" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Suppler/s Address:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sup_address" name="sup_address" placeholder="Supplier's Address" value="{{$suppliers->supplier_address}}" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Contact Person" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Contact Person:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="con_person" name="con_person" placeholder="Contact Person Name" value="{{$suppliers->contact_person_name}}" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can select the suppliers name but I can't display its properties.

here's the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Po;
use App\Supplier;

class PoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $po = Po::All()->name();
        return view('/po.manage-po', compact('po'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $supplier = Supplier::All();
        return view('/po.add-po', compact('supplier'));
    }
```

Comment: if the supplier properties are single and no need for repeat, you can get it separately and pass it from controller along with the suppliers as an array.

Comment: can you update the question and add the controller code too?

Comment: please add your controller code.

Comment: i've updated the thread and put the controller

Comment: please `dd($supplier);` in the controller and add the output as well.